# Permanent redirect far alternate domain via Apache rewrite rules without affecting non-www of target domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to write a rule to permenantly redirect a domainname to another domain name

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.companyname1.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.companyname2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This only works if the user remembers to type in www, if the user does not type in www in the url, the page will load but the image links will be broken.

Does anyone know how to adjust the above rule to it works with and without www?

I am using a LAMP configuration, apache 2 on redhat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can supply several optional Rewrite-Conditions with [OR]:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.companyname1.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^companyname1.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.companyname2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This should do the trick. The first Rewrite-Condition fires, if www is present, the second one fires, if www has been forgotten.

Comment: The symbolic name [R=permanent]" instead of the numeric 301 is slightly more optimal as it will avoid confusion in your config. from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html use: "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.companyname2.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]"

Comment: For me the RewriteRule http://www.companyname2.com/$1 added an extra slash after the domain, so I had to replace it with http://www.companyname2.com$1

Comment: @Stickley Wow. "slightly more optimal". You _are_ aware the "optimal" is a superlative?

Comment: You should always take care about if it is a good idea to use `301` alias `permanent`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s

Answer (score 2):

The redirect was not working for me and I had to adjust it, below is a working version based on the answer by @Demento.

```
# Parmenent redirect to webdesign.danols.com of all pages
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.kingston-web-design.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kingston-web-design.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://webdesign.danols.com.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care what the hostname starts with then don't root the regex, just check that it ends with companyname1.com.

As for the leading slash just add it at as optional to the root of your regex.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} companyname1.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.companyname2.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just by using simple regex:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?companyname1\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.companyname2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```