# proper way to write your links for use on multiple domains

Tags: html, apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

If I have multiple domains all pointing to the same website,  how are you supposed to write your links so they do not break when used via a different domain, .e.g

Imagine I have the following domains for the same website

```
oshirowanen.com
oshiro_wanen.com
osh.i.ro.wa.nen.com
```

if I had a html link as follows

```
<img src="http://www.oshirowanen.com/images/me.jpg" />
```

That would only be displayed if users went to oshirowanen.com.

How should that img tag be done properly so it works on all 3 domains?

Comment: You shouldn't have the same website on multiple domains. Pick one to be canonical and redirect the others to it.

Comment: I second that, you need to look into your apache config to rewrite the others (probably the second and third) to copy urls over to the canonical site, e.g. http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CanonicalHostNames .

Comment: @Tchalvok, I'm trying to do that, but not having much luck: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553980/permanent-redirect-via-apache-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just

> ```
>  <img src="/images/me.jpg" />
> ```

Comment: Yes, to make it equivalent to the example in the question. (With the "/", it's relative to the root of the site; without the "/", it's relative to the URL of the HTML document.)

Answer (score 1):

Like this: `<img src="/images/me.jpg" />`, the src is from the root of whatever domain that page is accessed from.

Answer (score 0):

If all your domains point to the same index, then you can just use relative paths

```
<img src="images/me.jpg"/>
```

Comment: if it's relative to the the html files. if all of your html files are in a folder and you have the images folder inside that folder then the / is not needed.