# .htaccess redirect folder to a url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a folder and all its sub files to a URL with a .htaccess file.

But

```
Redirect 301 /abc/cba/ http://www.aaa.com/
```

Will make `/abc/cba/ddd/index.html` redirect to `http://www.aaa.com/ddd/index.html`

What I want is redirect `/abc/cba/ /abc/cba/ddd/index.html` to `http://www.aaa.com/`

Could anyone help? Thanks. If anything not clear, please let me know.

Comment: I have my shared hosting server on godaddy.com and primary domain is abc.com Now I have another domain registered xyz.com on some other 3rd service not on godaddy. For this new website xyz.com I have installed wordpress in xyz directory of my godaddy hosting server.

Now how do I point this xyz.com domain to my xyz directory of my hosting server by keeping abc.com website as it is?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

By default, `Redirect` sort of *maps* the path node to a new path node, so anything after the first path gets appended to the target URL.

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/abc/cba/ http://www.aaa.com/?
```

Or if you'd rather use mod_rewrite instead of mod_alias:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?abc/cba/ http://www.aaa.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Just a hint: You should be really sure if you want to use `301`. Because it really can be a real **permanent** redirect ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s ). If you are not sure and want to avoid trouble in future, use `302`. Anyway advantageous in the implementation and testing phase.

Comment: Does case mater? Would `/abc/CBA/` get redirected to `http://www.aaa.com/?` with the provided solution or do you need to account for casing options, too? Also, what does the `?` do for us?

Answer (score 10):

here's another example of a mod_rewrite rule that worked for me

I wanted to redirect a sub directory to the root of the same domain.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sub_directory/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

more examples can be found here:http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/

Answer (score 2):

I perfer the following method:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/somedir           [NC]
 RewriteRule /(.*) http://somesite.com/lost/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I had to reroute urls from old site version to new version, so here is what I did to reroute any links from about-us/* to about-us.html

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about-us/(.*)$ about-us.html [R=301,L]
```

What it doesn't do is rewrite something like *domain.com/about-us/thing.html => domain.com/about-us.html* .

It does work for things without extensions *domain.com/about-us/something-in-url => domain.com/about-us.html*

I added the lines below to redirect .jpg and .png, but it didn't work for .html, I can't find out why.

```
RewriteRule ^about-us/(.*).jpg about-us.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^about-us/(.*).png about-us.html [R=301,L]
```