# Redirect www.example.com/blog to blog.example.com on other server

Tags: apache, subdomain, redirect

I have two ec2 servers in which one is running my website and another is blog with sub-domain. Both are having apache2 installed.

How can i redirect `http://www.example.com/blog` to `blog.example.com`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite.

Create .htaccess file in root containing

```
RewriteEngine On 
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog http://blog.example.com/
```

Comment: hope it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715684/htaccess-redirect-folder-to-a-url

Comment: not working. Not Found The requested URL /blog was not found on this server.. Getting this error while trying to access `example.com/blog`

Comment: 1) Do you have installed mod_rewrite? 
2) In which folder did you put this file?

Comment: yes mod_rewrite is enabled. I put .htaccess in root folder of my website and my blog is running on another server with `blog.dvele.com` sub-domain . I want users to redirect from `example.com/blog` to `blog.exmaple.com`

Comment: .htaccess should be in the same folder as index.html.

Comment: yes .htaccess is in the same folder as index.html but still getting `Not Found The requested URL /blog was not found on this server` error

Comment: it looks like mod_rewrite is not working. Please check that options  "AllowOverride All" in your apache virtual hosts file. And you restart apache after enabled mod_rewrite.