# How redirect comma separated url with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

There are 2 different URLs `https://maldivesresorts.com.au/package/vakarufalhi-island-resort-all-meals-drinks/` and `https://maldivesresorts.com.au/package/vakarufalhi-island-resort-all-meals-drinks/` but while SEO audit I found the wrong url and it is showing like `https://maldivesresorts.com.au/luxury-resorts-study-vakarufalhi-maldives-resort/,https://maldivesresorts.com.au/package/vakarufalhi-island-resort-all-meals-drinks/,here` so I want to redirect the wrong url to another page.
So it should be redirect
to `/hot-deals`.

Here is my htaccess code but it doesn't seems working

```
RewriteEngine On
redirect /luxury-resorts-study-vakarufalhi-maldives-resort/,https://maldivesresorts.com.au/package/vakarufalhi-island-resort-all-meals-drinks/,here /hot-deals
```

Comment: The example doesn't contain spaces but the `.htaccess` contains spaces, is it a typo? Did you try to use quotes around the path?

Comment: no, its not the answer and yes there is typo

Comment: "There are 2 different URLs" - those 2 URLs are identical? Have you corrected the malformed link that is causing this error? What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

This is how redirects work:

[image]

ref: https://www.semrush.com/blog/htaccess-redirect/

So you should be doing:

```
RewriteEngine On 
redirect 301 /luxury-resorts-study-vakarufalhi-maldives-resort/ /hot-deals 
redirect 301 /package/vakarufalhi-island-resort-all-meals-drinks/ /hot-deals
```

However, you *look like* you're redirecting folders rather than files so you should simply look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715684/htaccess-redirect-folder-to-a-url) which your question appears to be a duplicate of.

Comment: Thanks for the answering but its a completely single url not multiple

Comment: @Vijay the URLs in your example are folders (they end in `/`). Please **edit** and update your question.

Comment: no these are not folder's path, its complete url which have category/tag sort of

Comment: @Vijay you are telling the system to redirect `/luxury-resorts-study-vakarufalhi-maldives-resort/` which is a folder path, even if it isn't a *real* folder path, that's what it looks like and you've done nothing to highlight or show any **Mod_Rewriting** you may be doing so we have no reason to think it's anything other than a folder path. Again, please can you **edit** and **clarify** your question.

Comment: @Vijay and does your htaccess currently have mod_rewrite operating?

Comment: yes, other redirects are working correctly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248469/discussion-between-vijay-and-martin).

Comment: _Aside:_ `Redirect` is a mod_alias directive. This has nothing to do with `RewriteEngine` (mod_rewrite).