# Issue in execution order with RewriteRules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, vanity-url

Due to marketing reasons, I'm using some vanity URL's for friendlier access, and to track some campaigns. Unfortunately, I'm stuck on a managed dedicated server, with cPanel, and these were the steps I took to write my rules:

- First, I added `xyz.com` and `efg.com` to parked domains in my cPanel
- Then I wrote all the `RewriteRule`s that I needed

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xyz\.com$
RewriteRule ^signdirections$ "http\:\/\/xyz\.abc\.com\/en?utm_source=signdirections&utm_medium=advert&utm_campaign=xyz" [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^efg\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.efg\.com$
RewriteRule ^signdirections$ "http\:\/\/efg\.abc\.com\/en?utm_source=signdirections&utm_medium=advert&utm_campaign=efg" [R=301,L]
```

Now, the problem is that if I try to access `www.efg.com/signdirections`, I will get redirected to the `www.xyz.com/signredirections` version, instead of efg's one.

Any idea, why that is happening? My intuition, is that it detects the same hostname (HTTP_HOST), but  I can't understand why.

Comment: you have no other rules causing redirections?

Comment: @hjpotter92 there are more redirecting rules, but the clash is only where there are duplicated RewriteRules (ex: signdirections) on different hosts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it is happening due to your other rules. Better to use `THE_REQUEST` variable that doesn't change after application of other rules.

You can also combine both your rules into one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(xyz|efg)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /signdirections [NC]
RewriteRule . http://%1.abc.com/en?utm_source=signdirections&utm_medium=advert&utm_campaign=%1 [R=301,L,NE,QSA]
```

- Make sure this is your first rule below `RewriteEngine On` line.
- Make sure to test it in a new browser to avoid old browser cache.

Comment: actually, it still doesn't do it :\

Comment: Ah you have `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)xyzabc\.com$ [NC]` missing for 2nd rule i.e. before line 4. Similarly missing before line 10.

Comment: :| wow... I was not expecting that. But hey, if that's how it has to be.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if that can be a cache error after a bad test:
[How long do browsers cache HTTP 301s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s)

Just a simplified version:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?xyz\.com$
RewriteRule ^signdirections$ http://xyz.abc.com/en?utm_source=signdirections&utm_medium=advert&utm_campaign=xyz [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?efg\.com$
RewriteRule ^signdirections$ http://efg.abc.com/en?utm_source=signdirections&utm_medium=advert&utm_campaign=efg [R=302,L]
```

Try with R=302, and when everything works, change for R=301