# my local port at 127.0.0.1:8000 always redirects to 127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/lists when no file redirects url django

Tags: python, django, http, url, backend

I am programming in Django and am having a rather odd problem.

I was previously using code that would redirect the url from 127.0.0.1:8000 to 127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/lists but have both changed that code and stopped the server.

Now even if no server is running if I go to 127.0.0.1:8000 it redirects to 127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/lists. And when I run the django dev server it goes to that address and then errors that nothing is at that address.

my current urls are:

in meta.urls

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url 

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'uploads.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'/list',include('uploads.urls')),
)
```

and
uploads.urls

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns,url

urlpatterns = patterns('uploads.views',
    url(r'^list/$','home',name='list'),
    )
```

my error on screen is

> Using the URLconf defined in meta.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order: ^$ [name='home'] /list ^list/$ [name='list']
>   The current URL, myapp/list/, didn't match any of these.

what could be the cause?

Comment: If no server is running and it sill redirects, that could be something like your hosts file, or something like apache or gunicorn is still running the old python. Just wild guesses.

Comment: you have set an permanent redirect which  is cached in your browser. Try clean your caches.

Comment: That was it. Thank you. I haven't been confronted by this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers cache 301 Redirects, and do not cache 302 Redirects. If you were using a 301 Redirect, you need to clear your browser cache. See this SO question for more info:

[How long do browsers cache HTTP 301s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s)