# How to remove 301 redirect from .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

I am trying to fix this issue with my website where a Redirect 301 is applied. Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect "/" to Landing
RewriteRule ^$ http://greenengineering.com.au/landing/ [R=301,L]

# Additionally, redirect "/index.html" to Landing
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.html$ /landing
```

Can anyone guide me on how to remove this Redirection so that user can access the main domain http://greenengineering.com.au?

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove the lines from your `.htaccess`. In case it does not work your browser [may have cached](https://superuser.com/questions/467999/clear-301-redirect-cache-in-firefox) the 301 redirect, as it is meant to be permanent. Try restarting your browser or use a another browser to check whether it worked.

Answer (score 2):

While developing it's better to use temporary redirects (302) until you are sure of your rules.

The lines below will permanently redirect

> http://greenengineering.com.au/  --> http://greenengineering.com.au/landing/

```
# Redirect "/" to /landing/
RewriteRule ^$ /landing/ [R=301,L]
```

The lines below will also permanently redirect

> http://greenengineering.com.au/index.html --> http://greenengineering.com.au/landing/

```
# Redirect "/index.html" to /landing/
RewriteRule ^index\.html /landing/ [L=301,L]
```

Remove the rules that you no longer wish to use. If you find that the 301 redirect is still happening, then please see [How can I make Chrome stop caching redirects?](https://superuser.com/questions/304589/how-can-i-make-chrome-stop-caching-redirects) and [How long do browsers cache HTTP 301s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s)