# URL change between onBeforeNavigate and onCommitted of chrome.webNavigation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When using the [chrome.webNavigation API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation), the following code (used in background page of an extension):

```
  chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function(data) {
    console.log('onCommitted', data.tabId, data.url);
  });
  chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(function(data) {
    console.log('onBeforeNavigate', data.tabId, data.url);
  });
```

produces this output when navigating to, say, 'http://drive.google.com'

```
newTest.js:18 onBeforeNavigate 606 http://drive.google.com/
newTest.js:18 onCommitted 606 https://drive.google.com/
```

Somewhere, even before the request was sent to the server, Chrome changed the url from **http** to **https**.

This behaviour is also exhibited in other cases. For instance for 'http://getpocket.com', where it also adds a new path:

```
newTest.js:18 onBeforeNavigate 626 http://getpocket.com/
newTest.js:18 onCommitted 626 https://getpocket.com/beta/
```

The server side redirects all come after *onCommitted*, but this is one case where Chrome modifies urls even before it sends a request to the server.

Is this behaviour documented somewhere, so I can predictably handle it?

Comment: Perhaps it's [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Google Drive, it's [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) kicking in.

After it's set up, the browser will automatically redirect everything to HTTPS.

You can look under the hood at net-internals, e.g. `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`

> static_sts_domain: drive.google.com
>   static_upgrade_mode: STRICT

---

In case of Pocket, this seems to be a `301 Moved Permanently` redirect.

By design, browsers cache this response **permanently** (at least [Chrome does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s)) and rewrite links automatically without hitting the server until said cache is cleared.

Comment: Possibly, in this case. But it also exhibits this behaviour in another case:

> newTest.js:18 onBeforeNavigate 626 http://getpocket.com/
> newTest.js:18 onCommitted 626 https://getpocket.com/beta/

Does HSTS also allow specifying a path?

Comment: Wait, do you have an extension for Pocket installed? It may be redirecting requests.

Comment: Inspect `chrome://net-internals/#events` to see what happens. It's the most detailed trace you'll get.

Comment: Nope, don't have a Pocket extension installed. Also checked HSTS: drive is configured in HSTS, Pocket isn't.