# How does bitly serve 301 Permanent redirects, but still track hits, and how can I do it in Django?

Tags: django, redirect, seo, http-status-codes, url-shortener

Serving a Permanent 301 redirect or a Temporary 302 redirect in Django is very straightforward using the [redirect shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/shortcuts/#redirect) (which in turn just uses HttpResponsePermanentRedirect or HttpResponseRedirect)

I need to count how many times a redirect was used, but if I use 301, my view is only hit on the first request.  Browsers presumably cache the new URL, because successive requests don't hit my view.

And yet I can see that many URL shortening services (http://searchengineland.com/analysis-which-url-shortening-service-should-you-use-17204) do use 301 AND count hits.

How do they do this?  I can see they write cookies, but I don't understand what this buys you?

Comment: Are you sure that the services are not just tracking the initial request?

Comment: [This post on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s) suggests to use `Cache-Control` header. Bit.ly sets `Cache-Control` header to private with `60` as expriation time.

Answer (score 0):

@Alisdair is correct. When I created a short url in various services and hit refresh, I saw the hit count increase, but did not consider that it was not actually me, but a bot watching newly created short URLs :)  Yes, 301 Permanent redirect allws them to track only the initial request.