# Code for temporary removal?

Tags: html, redirect, web

I know a 301 redirect is for a permanent change, and 302 is for a temporary change.

What code should I use when the page is offline for a number of weeks and in the mean time I am redirecting to the homepage? The page should be back up in a few weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect, it would be 302. If you don't want to redirect, you could send [`503 Service unavailable` and set a Retry-After header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.4) (which should hopefully prevent search engines from coming back before that time).

If you still want the end-user experience to be a redirect to the homepage, you might, with heavy heart, consider adding that to the content of your 503 error page with a `meta refresh` or something JavaScript based, and hope for the best in terms of what a search engine crawler makes of that.

[Previous answers suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21396547/505649) that browsers *might* honour cache and expires headers set on a 301 response, but since that fails-unsafe, I wouldn't rely on it. ([The standard](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2) says the response is "cacheable unless indicated otherwise"; its definition of 302 Found suggests a 302 that is explicitly cacheable might be cached, but it wouldn't be the first time browsers don't implement what could be read out of  the letter of the RFCs.)