# Url redirect on azure

Tags: azure, redirect, web-config

I have used web.config to redirect the url to a different website but after i remmove the line of code that redirects, the changes do not reflect and when i access the website i still get an redirect.
I have tried to restart the AppService plan but that does not work.
How can I change everything back as it was?

the code below i have written:

```
<rule name="[RULE NAME]" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="(.*)" />
     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="[OLD URL]" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="www.[OLD URL]" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" url="http://[NEW URL]" redirectType="Permanent"/>
     </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a Permanent redirect. That will result in a HTTP 301 code, which in most normal circumstances will be cached.

It *may* help to clear your browser's cache. Or try a different browser.

See [How long do browsers cache HTTP 301s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s).