# Should applications that store URLs first follow them and store the result after any 301 permanent redirects?

Tags: http, url, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I have an application which consumes rss feeds (could be anything though).  Users provide these feed urls and they often get 301 permanent redirects.  From a best practices point of view should I be storing the original url or the new url?

I assume the latter is more appropriate given that this is the purpose of the 301 redirect (as well as 308) and this is what crawlers do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the spec as saying to adopt the new location -- [301 Moved Permanently](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.2)

> Clients with link-editing capabilities ought to automatically re-link
> references to the effective request URI to one or more of the new
> references sent by the server, where possible.

Widespread browser behaviour ([How long do browsers cache HTTP 301s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s)) is to use the new URI indefinitely:

> Chrome and Firefox will cache a 301 redirect with no expiry date.

While you're asking for a general answer ("a best practices point of view"), there are reasons to retain the original URL instead (e.g., to avoid breaking with poorly-configured captive portals).

As always with HTTP, follow the spec as far as you can without creating a bad user experience in practice.

Comment: Joe - good point about following the spec...  By the way, also good point that different browsers handle this very differently.