# Disable 308 Redirect caching with node.js

Tags: node.js

How do I disable browsers default Redirect caching behavior using node.js?

I'm writing some code to Redirect http to https using 308 Permanent Redirect, using Location response header but I noticed if i change the location href browser still redirect to the old href I assigned earlier.
How do I disable this behavior?

Comment: Don’t use a permanent redirect if it’s not permanent? 307 is the equivalent temporary.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to Redirect my traffic to https://

Comment: So you accidentally served an incorrect redirect before and you want to clear it to try again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s