# HAproxy: Redirect to https in backend

Tags: redirect, haproxy

My workplace has a HAproxy which we use for routing to webservers needing only one public IP. Some of our customers want https some do not.

I would like to enforce https on a per backend basis.

I found this, only it does not say if this config is for frontend or backend. Maybe it will work for both?

> http-request redirect location  [code ] [] []

or this:

> mode http
>
> redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

So I thought Id put this in some of the  backends:

> http-request redirect location https://www.somedomain.com [code 301]

Will this work? Our lab env. is tied up so I cannot test it in a timely fashion.

Comment: Put these in the frontend.  When you're redirecting, there's geberally no reason for the request to even proceed to the point where a backend is selected.

Comment: I generally shy away from using 301 redirects, because there is no way to guarantee if/when the user will visit the redirected URL. From another answer: [`[P]revention is better than cure - avoid a 301 redirect if you are not sure you want to permanently de-commission the old URL`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21396547/6510524)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created my own test backend.. 
This works:

```
backend lb_customername
          mode http
          redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

          balance roundrobin

          server server1 10.0.0.51:80 maxconn 200
          server server2 10.0.0.52:80 maxconn 200
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the HAProxy documentation for `redirect scheme`](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-redirect%20scheme)

```
May be used in sections
defaults    no
frontend    yes
listen      yes
backend     yes
```

So this will work (copied from a working deployment)

```
backend https_for_all_traffic
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

    server https_only 10.21.5.73:80
```

Since the `!{ ssl_fc }` check is essentially just another ACL, you could even combine it with other ACLs and forward only certain traffic:

```
backend https_for_some_traffic
    # Detect traffic to admin pages
    acl secure    url_beg    /admin

    # Force any HTTP admin traffic to HTTPS
    #  the conditions are combined with an implicit AND
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc } secure

    server both_http_and_https 10.21.5.73:80
```