# Google Chrome failing to clear the cache

Tags: google-chrome, caching, nginx

I am creating a new web site, where I was redirecting HTTP traffic on port 80 to port 443, using certificates created by Certbot. I was using NginX as a reverse proxy for Apache2, so all requests for PHP scripts were to be served from Apache.

I encountered a problem, and decided to remove the HTTPS redirection, stop the Apache server, and start again from the beginning. In other words, I now had Nginx working on its own, and just on port 80.

When testing in Google Chrome 62.0.3202.75, I dutifully cleared the cache. Many times. However Chrome continued to redirect my requests for `http://sub.domain.com/index.php` to `https://sub.domain.com/index.php`, which of course failed. Other browsers were happy to download the `index.php` file, with no complaints.

It was only when I decide to restore the original default settings for Chrome that Chrome started to behave correctly again.

How is it that Chrome was determined to unilaterally perform a redirect that was no longer valid, even after emptying the cache? Is there a more powerful way (other than restoring settings their original defaults) of getting Chrome to let go of a page?

Comment: Might be a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s

Comment: @ShawnC. Thanks! It looks like going to chrome://net-internals and clearing the cache from there is the right amount of powerful. `https://stackoverflow.com/a/35093587/1927589`