# URL always have public_html before the file name

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel

Whenever I go to a page, like `payment.php`,the URL always become `www.website.com/public_html/payment`. I don't have any `.htaccess` anymore in both `public_html` and the root.

This happened after I tried using [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/805287/htaccess-remove-php-extension-only-for-specific-files-or-folder), and even if I deleted my `.htaccess`, it still adds `public_html` in the URL.

This is the rules that I added *(I already deleted the file so I'm expecting that no rewriting should happen anymore)*:

```
# Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]

# Force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

How to revert it back to the default?

***Note:*** I don't really know much about this, so please comment for what other info should I add

Comment: When you had `.htaccess` what rules you had written in it? Can you post it along with the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you provided shows that the .htaccess file served the responses as 301 redirects which is cached by browsers. You can try a simple browser restart to see if that fixes the problem.

Otherwise, you might find relevant information here:

[How long do browsers cache HTTP 301s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s)

Comment: I restarted chrome, but still the rewriting happens. So I tried opening it in firefox, and it does not happen there. So I guess it is cache after all

Comment: The cache is permanent. For Chrome, from the linked article, you can try:

To clear a permanent redirect, go to chrome://net-internals. On the 
right of the top red status bar, click on the down arrow ▼ to open the 
drop-down menu, and under the "Tools" group, choose "Clear cache".