# Redirect localhost address in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, localhost

I am using XAMPP as the server on my PC and running WordPress on it. 
I have changed the site address and home address in the database. In Option field 
it has been changed.

Then I changed it back again to its initial state, but it did not change the second time. The result is I can not access my localhost address and it is redirecting to another address in localhost. 
I even removed my database and re-installed WordPress. 
But the old address already exists and I can not access my localhost address.

When I type localhost in my address bar in Chrome it will redirect to localhost/1/. 
It has been cached somewhere.

How can I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It must have cached by your browser, Check with other browsers and also clear browser cache.
Read the on same topic here, it would be helpful [How long do browsers cache HTTP 301s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s)