# My site is redirect to another site, I don't know why?

Tags: php, .htaccess

When my site redirect to with www I wrote below code in htaccess, mistakenly I forgot instead of example.com I placed example.org, it redirects to example.org now, I found my mistake and replaced with .com instead of .org, in browser I tested its redirect default to .org.

I don't know why its redirect to another site with .org. Is there any cache? How to resolve it?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]


 www.example.com is redirect to www.example.org
```

Comment: Try it in a different browser,  I have 5 browsers... lol

Comment: Clear browser data

Comment: And this is why 301 redirects are dangerous. 301 is a permanent redirect, and you've basically told your browser, your provider, and every bit of proxy, cache and who knows what that your site will always redirect to .org, and they never have to ask again (that is, not in the next year).

Comment: Clear your cache and try again.

Comment: i tried different broswers, i checked and i cleared cache in browsers, same problem repeated.

Comment: how to resolve @GolezTrol

Comment: Could be that you are behind a "clever" caching proxy. Then there is no way to undo this other than resetting that proxy, to which you probably don't have access to.

Comment: Can you check the developer tools if the browsers fetch the page from cache? If they do, you have to (better) clear the browser cache. If they don't, it's cached somewhere else, and you may have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

see this posting:

> • The simplest and best solution is to issue another 301 redirect back
>   again.
>
> The browser will realise it is being directed back to what it
>   previously thought was a de-commissioned URL, and this should cause it
>   re-fetch that URL again to confirm that the old redirect isn't still
>   there.
>
> Edit: some comments throw doubt upon this, see below.
>
> • If you don't have control over the site where the previous redirect
>   target went to, then you are outta luck. Try and beg the site owner to
>   redirect back to you.

and also this one:

> Make the user submit a post form on that url and the cached redirect
>   is gone

[How long do browsers cache HTTP 301s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s)