# Code in my .htaccess causing too many redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have added to my .htaccess the following code

```
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [R=302,L]
```

with the rest of code in .htaccess it 's causing too many redirects

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /slovnik-pojmu.*/.*/
 RewriteRule (.*)-([^\/]+)/(.*)/ /index.php?page=$1&mid=$2&word=$3 [L,QSA]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*poslat-odkaz.*/$
 RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [R=302,L]
```

Do you have any idea what is causing the redirects?

I'm testing this address: www.energy21.cz/kontakt-190

Comment: What is your address you enter in the address bar that causes the infinite redirect loop?

Comment: www.energy21.cz/kontakt-190

Comment: I have no real idea. You have to check all the rules and comment them out with a `#` and control, which one is responsible for this behavior. **BEWARE**: `RewriteCond` and following `RewriteRule` belong together and should be commentet out simultaniously.