# New tab target blank url opens in Chrome and IE but not in Microsoft Edge

Tags: angular, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I'm having a link with target blank and it opens in Chrome giving 200 with the correct page requested. But for MS Edge it gives 301(301 Moved Permanently) without page response. Also it first try to load the URL and it's visible even in the address bar but goes to a default setting URL. For security reasons I cant share the actual link here. But seems it works with Chrome and IE, code level there is no bug. Any idea or any additional attributes that I should use on the anchor tag?

Comment: Which version of Microsoft Edge are you using? Try to clear the browser data (cache and history and so on), and then re-check the website, whether the problem is solved. Besides, you could also try to repair or reset the Edge browser.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT, it's actually a customer facing application. So want a general solution regardles of the browser version of Edge

Comment: Yeah, I know that.But from your description, I'm not sure whether this issue only happens on your machine and the special version version of Microsoft Edge, or this issue happens on all the versions of Microsoft Edge on different machines.So, I want to confirm with you about that. Besides, I have searched some related threads and article(such as: [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/), [Link2](https://community.apigee.com/questions/26552/how-to-handle-301-moved-permanently-redirect-url-i.html)),  it seems that this issue might be related browser cache,so, try to clear the cache.