# django searches for url which does not exist in my current project. Why is this happening? The project used to exist but no longer

Tags: python, django

i used to have an app in a project called catalog but i have deleted the project upon completion. Currently i have started a new project, but i have realised that the django searches for catalog which was an app in the old project. Instead of django searching for urls in my new project. i uninstalled anaconda and reinstalled it with django to see whether that will solve the issue but it still remains. One thing i noted was that in the previous project which contained catalog as a app i imported the Redirect View and redirected the homepage which was empty to the url of the app so that it rather acts as the index. Now whenever i run the server it points to the page where the redirect was done in my current project which does not exist throwing the exception below.

Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/

Using the URLconf defined in main.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
```

The current path, catalog/, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by the hard redirect `http 301` which you did on your old app for `127.0.0.1:8000`. I would suggest looking through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s) to find your solution.

Answer (score 1):

On firefox, go to settings, move to privacy and security, lookup Cookies and Site Date and clear them. This fixes the problem.