# Apache 2.4.41 - unable to connect on localhost multiple virtualhost / ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed apache2 on my laptop, and created a virtual host to work on a site for development. This is working fine. I now need to add a second site, and have come across issues, despite the setup being identical to the first (working) vhost config.

Whenever i access the second site, the request is redirected to https (even if http is defined), and the browser returns a "unable to connect" error page.

http://dev.mysite.co.uk > loads ok

http://dev.mysite2.co.uk > redirects to https://dev.mysite2.co.uk, and "unable to connect" message

I have looked into the problem for the past few evenings and tried many suggestions, including www/ dir permissions, but none have worked.

Site 1 config, located in /etc/apache2/sites-available (working without issue):

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerName dev.mysite1.co.uk
>     DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite1/public_html
>
>     <Directory /var/www/mysite1/public_html>
>         Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
>         AllowOverride All
>     </Directory>
>
>     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite1.co.uk-error.log
>     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite1.co.uk-access.log combined 
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

Site 2 config, located in /etc/apache2/sites-available:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.mysite2.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite2/public_html

    <Directory /var/www/mysite2/public_html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite2.co.uk-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite2.co.uk-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

...both enabled via a2ensite.

/etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   dev.site2.co.uk
127.0.0.1   dev.site1.co.uk 
127.0.0.1   phpmyadmin
127.0.1.1   mymachine

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback fe00::0 ip6-localnet ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix ff02::1 ip6-allnodes ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Output of apachectl configtest:

> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
> Syntax OK

(i have previously set "ServerName localhost" in apache2.conf, which removed the first FQDN message, but didn't affect the issue i am having). Both have symlinks to the vhost confgs in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled. Apache2.conf is standard / no default to standard installation. Browser extensions disabled / same result in different browsers.

Output of ls -ld /var/www/site1:

> drwxrwxrwx 10 me me 4096 Jan 15 20:50 /var/www/site1

Output of ls -ld /var/www/site2:

> drwxrwxr-x 9 me www-data 4096 May 17 22:45 /var/www/site2

Is the difference in site2 having www-data permissions? Which should be apache-user readable?

No difference made by chown -R 755 /var/www

Also realised that http://localhost is also redirecting to https://localhost and an "unable to connect" message.

http://localhost/phpmyadmin works fine.

Output of apachectl -S:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server dev.site1.co.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site1.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost dev.site1.co.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site1.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost dev.site2.co.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site2.conf:1) 
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2" 
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html" 
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log" 
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default  
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults 
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults 
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults 
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid" 
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS 
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG 
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used 
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question mentions 5 different hostnames.

- dev.mysite.co.uk
- dev.mysite1.co.uk
- dev.mysite2.co.uk
- dev.site1.co.uk
- dev.site2.co.uk

The apache configs don't match the apachectl output and the /etc/hosts contents.

So, you edited *something*.

The below is conjecture, as it isn't known which parts are edited.

Could this be happening:
For the first site, all is well, but for the second, your request does not match the config or hosts-entry, so the browser tries https and fails because dev.site2.co.uk and dev.mysite2.co.uk do not exist in dns.

You could look in the logfiles to see if this is the case: If there are no log-entries for [my]site2, the hosts-entry is a likely culprit.

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be related to **301 redirect caching**. E.g. In the past you've set a `301`  redirect ([Moved Permanently](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301) ) towards `https` and now it is cached in the browser(s).

If this is the case, the following links may help find a solution:

- [How long do browsers cache HTTP 301s?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21396547/1555615)
- [Clear the 301/302 redirection cache (Chrome)](https://dev.to/epranka/clear-the-301-302-redirection-cache-chrome-4dio)

Note: you may first try with browsers, **that did not use the specific domain in the past**, or `curl/wget` and check whether they face the same problem. If not, most probably it is the caching problem.

**Other possible causes:**

- A browser addon operating in the concept of ( [https-everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) ) (But as you've said:  "Browser extensions disabled / same result in different browsers.")
- [iptables rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205871) that redirect http to https.
- Some [forgotten apache rule](https://serverfault.com/a/1059312) operating on all domains.

Note about `dev.mysite.co.uk`: You mention that it works ok, but I do not see any configuration about that domain. Is it a typo?