# Rails 7 | User Logging Out Automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, session-cookies, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a rails app in production and i am having cookie problem.

i have,

`www.domain.com`
`domain.com`

so my payment processor is logging the user out after a payment transaction if i use `domain.com`

So Later i made `domain.com` permenant redirect to `www.domain.com` and my payment processor url is also `www.domain.com/blah`.

so in my laptop, when i type `domain.com`  it is redirecting me to `www.domain.com`

However in my mobile, in google chrome , when i type `domain.com` it is being redirected to `domain.com` only.

Conclsion: it is redirecting `domain.com` to `www.domain.com` only on laptop but in Mobile Phones it is not.

I also included `permenant redirect / www.domain.com`  in my apache2 .conf file but still in phone if i type `domain.com`, it is redirecting to `domain.com` only

Also in my Google Domain, i have TYPE A `www.domain.com` which points to an IP address and no other dns configured.

Comment: Try it from incognito mode on mobile. It could be a caching issue on the phone.

Comment: i tried in incognito, and it is working, domain.com is redirecting me to www.domain.com  , So does this mean other users which they never visited domain.com in their life will be redirected www.domain.com?? in their phone also??

Comment: I would say so. Pretty much sounds like a caching issue. You may want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s

Answer (score 1):

If we use JWT token,

we have to put expired_at time for JWT token like below:

```
JWT.encode({id: 1, exp: 1.month.from_now} )
```