# How to fix 301 redirect loop in the client browser

Tags: redirect, browser-cache, http-status-code-301

I have two domains. Let's say `aaa.com` and `bbb.com`. `Aaa.com` was for a long time redirected to bbb.com with a 301.

`bbb.com` is the site that is currently live but this is on the domain that we do not want to be the main domain anymore.

We now want to start using `aaa.com` as the main domain.
The users browsers however have a 301 redirect cached from `aaa.com` to `bbb.com`.

How can I fix this so that I can automatically break this loop without expecting the users to remove their cache.

I was thinking of some solutions where I use a third domain or a subdomain temporarily, but can't think of a real good idea. Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

[image]

```
flowchart TD
  aaa.com -->|301| bbb.com
  bbb.com -->|Need this one| aaa.com
```

Not sure how relevant it is, but `aaa.com` is already available in CloudFlare, `bbb.com` is on another hosting. I also have access to the code of both websites, so can do something in there too. Changing DNS records are also an option.

Comment: I have not verified this personally, but, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21396547/87698), all major browsers should detect the loop and re-fetch `aaa.com`.

Comment: interesting, I haven't actually tried it, since I was scared of it. Now I have a link on the one bbb.com to aaa.com but that is just refreshing aaa.com due to the redirect